Angular - Input Signal not working in child component
Parent
   <app-rounded-divider
              [dividerColor]="true"
              [active]="isActive"
              />

Child
  /* i/o signals */
  public active = input<boolean>(false)
  public dividerColor = input<boolean>(false)


  ngAfterViewInit(){
    console.log(this.dividerColor())
  }

Keeps returning false? I must be missing something obvious. In the parent, app-rounded-divider is generated via a for loop, but I'm passing in "true", not a variable. Doesn't work, whether I do [dividerColor]="true", or dividerColor="true"


Your code seems to be working fine in this StackBlitz

It does work on StackBlitz. I'm going to restart my IDE (JetBrains Ultimate)

Ahh, I'm being a fool! I was looking at the wrong component in the IDE.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-qkqqkf?file=src%2Fapp%2Frounded-divider%2Frounded-divider.component.html

oof, it happens... yah just checked and should work fine, just make sure angular version up to date since the input signals are a bit of WIP feature but appears to be working today :D glad you sorted it out

Not an issue. Was looking at wrong component in IDE.
